# How to implement a ListView within a TabView?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I have a question about the implementation of a `ListView` layout within a tab layout.

When we are implementing this where we have a Custom title bar underneath which is a Tab Layout and within each Tab layout is a List View , should the main activity be a extension of `ListView` or should it be a extension of Tab View ? Can it be List View ?

The reason is that I've created a `ListView` properly functioning and I want to expand on it by using the list as a template and adding Tabs (categories) which branches into more of such lists. I've done it using `ListView` and seems like addition of tabs would require that i rewrite my whole code by extending `tabview`. Is there any way i can make use of `ListView` while implementing my tabs ?

I have noticed that there is no tutorial on how to implement these 2 views/layouts together, anyone has any links and directions ?

Comment: You should use ActivityGroup rather then Activity in this case and add activity group in a single tab the activity group able to control more then one activity at a time.

Comment: Hi Dynamic mind, thanks ! i think its a good point to be exploring, would it be fine if you have any good tutorials to find out more about how it can be used ? i know i can always google for it but do you have any good personal recommendations on a ActivityGroup tutorial ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got an example of this in some code I wrote a while ago.

What I needed was also a list inside of a tab. So the driver for this is the tab that has other activities inside it. You add TabSpec's that have the Intent of the ListActivity to the TabHost.

This is the layout for the tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Then this is the layout for one of the list views in the tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/no_items"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code for the tab itself:

public class

```
MyTabActivity extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.my_tabs);
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
            TabHost.TabSpec spec;
            Intent intent;

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyListActivity.class);
            spec = tabHost  .newTabSpec("some_things")
                            .setIndicator("Some")
                            .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyOtherActivity.class);
            spec = tabHost  .newTabSpec("top_things")
                            .setIndicator("Top")
                            .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);


            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 35;
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 35;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi rachel , thanks! I would suppose then that within each of the respective tabs_activity is a listactivity which will populate each tab into their individual lists ?

Comment: Yes, you add the ListActivities to the TabHost in the TabActivity java code and these ListActivites control the lists that they show. The TabActivity just knows what it should show in each pane, the ListActivities know what to show in their list.